# Cannot interacted with Google Maps on Flutter Web (google_maps)

Tags: visual-studio, google-maps, flutter, dart

I am just learn about `Flutter` for website.

I need to add some google map javascript API and using `google_maps` dependencies on `pub.dev`

I follow the example from here, but after debugging with `VSCode`, i found that I cannot interact with the map at all. No hand tools to drag the map, ore even just to click the maps mode (satellite or map mode).

I have tried several example from the example link, from the basics to the controlled example. But I still cannot interact with it. No error on terminal, and the web browser console. Anyone can give me some clue to make this work properly?

Here is the `google_maps` example:

https://github.com/a14n/dart-google-maps/tree/master/example

Thank You,
Cheers

Comment: I found that after debug and build, there is a additional element called `flt-ruler-host` that prevent me to access the googlemaps. Anyone can give me an advice about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i checked that a `flt-ruler-host` element appeared above the html rendered by flutter, i add z-index on maps canvas id, and everything working properly

Comment: Where do you change the z-index value? also what z-index value did you set it to?